# Baby versions of custom entities will follow adults of ANY species?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons, minecraft-behavior-packs

Not sure whether this is a bug or intentional, but for custom entities added via Bedrock addon packs, it is possible for the baby version to pick an adult of a different species to follow.

This was surprising to see, so I referred to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/reference/content/entityreference/examples/entitygoals/minecraftbehavior_follow_parent?view=minecraft-bedrock-stable) to see if I had made a mistake in my `.json` file, but it does not appear that I did.

Relevant component from my custom mob's JSON file:

```
"minecraft:behavior.follow_parent": {
    "priority": 5,
    "speed_multiplier": 1
}
```

The [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breeding#Baby_mobs) says (emphasis added):

> "Most baby animals choose and follow an adult within 8 blocks of the **same species**, regardless of whether it is their parent. Babies can choose new targets to follow whenever they do not have a valid target, such as when the previous target dies or moves further than 16 blocks away. Tamed pups and kittens follow their owner if the parent is absent or sitting."

So, it appears that baby *vanilla* mobs cannot follow an adult of a different species.

I'm wondering whether this is a known issue affecting custom entities from addons, and whether anyone else has observed this happening. I have noticed the baby version of one of my custom neutral mobs following both passive and hostile species' adults (which are *also* custom entities, all from the same addon pack).

---

Here are the custom entities' type families, in case this is relevant:

Neutral mob:

```
"minecraft:type_family": {
    "family": [ "cat", "mob" ]
}
```

Hostile mob:

```
"minecraft:type_family": {
    "family": ["monster", "mob"]
}
```

Passive mob:

```
"minecraft:type_family": {
    "family": ["mushroomcow", "mob"]
}
```